# Using one style, bind several objects to a list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have N DataPoints and an N-length list of strings. I want to make a style resource that I can apply to every DataPoint that will bind every TextBlock to an element in the list. Something like this

```
<Style TargetType="charting:DataPoint" x:Key="annotatedChart">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="CornflowerBlue"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:DataPoint">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle
                            Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Stroke="Black"/>
                        <Grid
                            Background="#aaffffff"
                            Margin="0 -20 0 0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <TextBlock
                                x:Name="textBox"
                                Text="{Binding}"   <!--TODO -->
                                FontWeight="Bold"
                                Margin="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I need to bind that text to a list so that every data point with this style will display a matching text element from a list. I have tried setting the DataContext of my main window to several objects and properties but all to no avail. At one time, my DataPoints were displaying the Dependent and Independent values but never anything from my list of strings.

Comment: OK, you forgot to ask a question though. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried a lot of stuff that appears to have gotten me nowhere. Most of it involves manipulating the DataContext of the main window but it hasn't helped at all.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but look at this http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out. I made a dictionary of independent values and labels, set it as the DataContext of my window, and bound the textbox to it with an IValueConverter that finds the dependent value in the dictionary and maps it to the label.

```
<TextBlock
            x:Name="textBox"
            Text="{Binding Key, Converter={StaticResource annotationsConverter}}"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Margin="2"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

and

```
public class myAnnotationsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (MainWindow.annotations != null)
        {
            try
            {
                return MainWindow.annotations[value as string];
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException e)
            {
                return "NULL";
            }

        }
        throw new NotFiniteNumberException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotFiniteNumberException();
    }
}
```

Possible improvement: support more than one column per category in the category axis. So, if I have three bars for June-2007, maintain a distinct label for all of them.